# Inheritance in database creates unnecessary foreign key column in superclass table

Tags: c#, database-design, inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am having an issue with how the database is being generated for an inheritance relationship in my entity classes.  It is correctly making the primary key ID in the subclass table reference the ID in the superclass table - but it is also creating a foreign key in the superclass table which it doesn't need.  Here are my classes:

Abstract superclass:

```
public abstract class DaqObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AgencyID { get; set; }
    public int DaqObjectTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AgencyID")]
    public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DaqObjectTypeID")]
    public virtual DaqObjectType DaqObjectType { get; set; }

    public virtual Document InheritingDocument { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding database table has the following columns:

- ID (PK, int, not null)
- AgencyID (FK, int, not null)
- DaqObjectTypeID (FK, int, not null)
- InheritingWell_ID (FK, int, null)

Subclass:

```
public class Document : DaqObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With a corresponding database table with the following columns:

- ID (PK, FK, int, not null)
- Name (nvarchar(max), null)

(These classes have been slimmed down for the example.)

The DaqObject table in the database ends up with an InheritingDocument_ID column.  I can create the database myself and make the relationship without that foreign key in the superclass table.  Is it possible to have EF code first do the same?

Comment: Can you post how do all columns in both tables look like?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my question to include that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InheritingDocument` in the `DaqObject` tells EF to create one:many relationship between `Document` and `DaqObject` entities. That's why there is the `InheritingDocument_ID` column in your DB.

I suppose, it isn't what you want, you have added the `InheritingDocument` property to make inheritance work, right? It isn't necessary, EF will take care of inheritance handling automatically. There is a nice [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx), that describes possible strategies for working with inherited classes with the EF.

Comment: Thanks, the line in the article you shared, "Code First will find the other classes in the hierarchy based on Reachability Convention," helped.  I removed the Document DbSet and also the InheritingDocument property, and now the database looks exactly how I want.

Answer (score 0):

InheritingDocumentID is the field generated for property

```
public virtual Document InheritingDocument { get; set; }
```

That relation is created by default by EF.

It is unclear, however what is `InheritingWell_ID (FK, int, null)` field, I'm thinking the code you posted is missing something.

You can add `[NotMapped]` attribute to InheritingDocument property to avoid generating field for it, but for this to work, you need also to add DbSet to db context, and that will five you [Table Per Hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) (one table for all types in hierarchy) which is faster but it is not in 3NF.

Comment: It looks like I was not supposed to include the InheritingDocument property for the inheritance relationship.  I removed that property from DaqObject and also the Document DbSet from the context and that fixed it.  Thanks for your assistance.